# cut some rows and columns where values are 255

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to get rid of all rows and columns in a grayscale numpy array where the values are 255.
My array could be:

```
arr = [[255,255,255,255],
       [255,0,0,255],
       [255,255,255,255]]
```

The result should be:

```
arr = [0,0]
```

I can just interating over the array, but there should be a pythonic way to solve the problem.
For the rows i tried:

```
arr = arr[~(arr==255).all(1)]
```

This works really well, but i cannot find an equal solution for colums.

Comment: What if the last row were `[255, 255,   0, 255]` instead, what must be the output then?

Answer (score 2):

Given boolean arrays for rows and columns:

```
In [26]: rows
Out[26]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [27]: cols
Out[27]: array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

[`np.ix_`](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pbechler/numpy_doc/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) creates ordinal indexers which can be used to index `arr`:

```
In [32]: np.ix_(rows, cols)
Out[32]: (array([[1]]), array([[1, 2]]))

In [33]: arr[np.ix_(rows, cols)]
Out[33]: array([[0, 0]])
```

Therefore you could use

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[255,255,255,255],
       [255,0,0,255],
       [255,255,255,255]])
mask = (arr != 255)
rows = mask.all(axis=1)
cols = mask.all(axis=0)
print(arr[np.ix_(rows, cols)])
```

which yields the 2D array

```
[[0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the columns, you can simply transpose the array:

```
arr = arr.T[~(arr.T==255).all(1)].T
arr = arr[~(arr==255).all(1)]
```

which results in

```
>> print(arr)
[[0 0]]
```